# Handling cronjobs in a Pod with multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a requirement in which I need to create a cronjob in kubernetes but the pod is having multiple containers (with single container its working fine).

Is it possible?

The requirement is something like this:
1. First container: Run the shell script to do a job.
2. Second container: run fluentbit conf to parse the log and send it.

Previously I thought to have a deployment in place and that is working fine but since that deployment was used just for 10 mins jobs I thought to make it a cron job.

Any help is really appreciated.

Also about the cronjob I am not sure if a pod can support multiple containers to do that same.

Thank you,
Sunny

Comment: If the order of execution comes into play (script must do something before the app starts) you could try to run an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) with your `Cronjob`

Answer (score 5):

I need to agree with the answer provided by @Arghya Sadhu. It shows how you can run multi container `Pod` with a `CronJob`. Before the answer I would like to give more attention to the comment provided by @Chris Stryczynski:

> It's not clear whether the containers are run in parallel or sequentially

---

It is not entirely clear if the workload that you are trying to run:

> The requirement is something like this:
>
> 1. First container: Run the shell script to do a job.
> 2. Second container: run fluentbit conf to parse the log and send it.

could be used in `parallel` (both running at the same time) or require `sequential` approach (after X completed successfully, run Y).

If the workload could be run in parallel the answer provided by @Arghya Sadhu is correct, however if one workload is depending on another, I'd reckon you should be using `initContainers` instead of multi container `Pods`.

The example of a `CronJob` that implements the `initContainer` could be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: ubuntu
              image: ubuntu
              command: [/bin/bash]
              args: ["-c","cat /data/hello_there.txt"]
              volumeMounts:
              - name: data-dir
                mountPath: /data
          initContainers:
          - name: echo
            image: busybox
            command: ["bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", "echo 'General Kenobi!' > /data/hello_there.txt"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: data-dir
              mountPath: "/data"
          volumes:
          - name: data-dir
            emptyDir: {}
```

This `CronJob` will write a specific text to a file with an `initContainer` and then a "main" container will display its result. It's worth to mention that the main container will not start if the `initContainer` won't succeed with its operations.

- `$ kubectl logs hello-1234567890-abcde`

```sh
General Kenobi!
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Linchpiner.github.io: K8S multi container pods](https://linchpiner.github.io/k8s-multi-container-pods.html)*

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can create a cronjob with multiple containers. CronJob is an abstraction on top of pod. So in the pod spec you can have multiple containers just like you can have in a normal pod. As an example

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: default
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          - name: app
            image: alpine
            command:
            - echo
            - Hello World!
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Hi Arghya, I did the same but unfortunately that didn't worked.. let me try to dig into it.. thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: I have tried the yaml in the answer and it worked...did it give any error?

Comment: Yes got it, the second container was throwing an error and the task was not having a clean exit :)

Comment: What kind of error did you get ? Please provide more information/

Comment: It's not clear whether the containers are run in parallel or sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Whats about sidecar container for logging as second container which keep running without exit code. Even the job might run the state of the job still failed.

Comment: It is better to provide some code, rather than words.